# Complete the sentence

Tags: cipher

I forgot to bring my **110 69 119 67 101 108 76 112 72 111 78 101**.

*Hint:*

> 104 73 110 84.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> new cellphone.

Explanation:

> ASCII. See ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/): "104 73 110 84" = "hInT" and "110 69 119 67 101 108 76 112 72 111 78 101" = "nEwCelLpHoNe".

And yes, I am quick :-) I liked the style of the hint, but the puzzle was way too easy IMO.

Comment: i just realized that it was too easy, maybe i should have encrypted it before i converted to it's equivalent decimal.

Comment: More than that it's easy, the issue is that the encoding is absolutely standard and the first thing many people check.

Comment: @xnor and pretty distinctive - only containing numbers between 60 and 120 is one of the biggest telltale signs you can get :)