# Finish The Pattern #2

Tags: calculation-puzzle, pattern, number-sequence

Given a pattern:

0, 1, 2, 0.5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, $n$

Find the next item at $n$.

*Pattern/sequence explanation required*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is

> 2.

Explanation:

> For each $k$, the $4k$th term is the sum of the $(4k-3)$th and $(4k-2)$th terms divided by the $(4k-1)$th term. Thus: (0+1)/2=0.5; (2+3)/5=1; (2+0)/2=1; (4+2)/3=**2**.

I got this answer by noticing that 0,1,2 and 2,3,5 are the starts of well-known sequences, so it seems likely that the $4k$th term is always a fixed function of the preceding 3 terms.

Comment: Correct! And under 2 minutes?.. Nice job.

Comment: @zachgates7 Gotta get in there quick before someone else does! :-) I've done it [before](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/complete-the-sentence/13238#13238) today as well. There should be a badge for this...

Comment: There certainly should be! More sequences are on the way :-)

Comment: @ZachGates I [raised the possibility](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2982/5373) of having a badge for this, but apparently people don't like it...